# Why isn't my text being drawn correctly on retina dispaly

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsstring, uibezierpath, uigraphicscontext

I am trying to draw some text and it's fine on non-retina displays, but on a retina display it's not high-res.

Here's a screenshot from my iPad Air:

[image]

See below for the code, which actually draws the text semi-transparent with an almost opaque mask around it, so you can see the image through the text.

```
-(void) maskImage:(UIImageView *)imageView withText:(NSString *)text font:(UIFont *)font attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes yOffset:(CGFloat)yOffset 
{ 
  NSStringDrawingContext *paraContext = [[NSStringDrawingContext alloc] init];
  NSStringDrawingOptions stringDrawingOptions = NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingTruncatesLastVisibleLine;

  // find out how much space we need for the text
  CGSize textSize = CGSizeIntegral([text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(kNowPlayingTrackDetailsMaxWidth, kNowPlayingTrackDetailsMaxHeight) options:stringDrawingOptions attributes:attributes context:paraContext].size);

  // set up the frame for drawing the text, including some padding

  CGSize drawingSize = {textSize.width + 80, textSize.height + 60};
  CGRect drawingFrame = { 0, 0, drawingSize.width, drawingSize.height};
  CGRect textFrame = { 40, 30, textSize.width, textSize.height };

  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(drawingSize, YES, 0);

  UIColor *bgColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:.98];
  [bgColor setFill];
  [bgColor setStroke];

  UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:drawingFrame];
  [path fill];

  // draw the text

  [text drawWithRect:textFrame options:stringDrawingOptions attributes:attributes context:paraContext];
  UIImage *textImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  // now create an image mask from the text image

  CIImage *inputImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:textImage.CGImage];
  CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIMaskToAlpha" keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, inputImage, nil];
  CIImage *outputImage = [filter outputImage];

  imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:outputImage];

  // final set the UIImageView size to match the drawing size
  CGRect imageViewFrame = imageView.frame;
  imageViewFrame.size = drawingSize;
  imageView.frame = imageViewFrame;
}
```

Comment: what is the size of the mask in _pixels_ and in _points_? I mean, have you scaled up the mask image for retina resolution?

Comment: Have you tried the scale factor while beginning image context like this:  `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(drawingSize, YES, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);`

Comment: @holex, I'm pretty sure I'm using points everywhere, as shown in my code.

Comment: @AdilSoomro I have tried that. Passing 0 for the scale parameter tells UIGraphics to use the scale of the main screen.

Comment: What's the scale of `outputImage`?

Comment: What effect would CGContextSetShouldAntiAlias(NO) have? (or similar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oliver Jones helped me solve this. Thanks @orj!

The answer is to create the UIImage with

```
    [UIImage imageWithCIImage:outputImage scale:textImage.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
```

instead of

```
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:outputImage];
```

This correctly sets the scale of the output image.